# .htaccess setting error_reporting with multiple PHP constants

Tags: php, .htaccess, logging, error-handling

I want set up own error_log without some error types over htaccess.

Like this:
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED`

error_reporting = E_ALL(32767) & ~E_NOTICE(8) & ~E_WARNING(2) & ~E_DEPRECATED(8192)

So it should be `php_value error_reporting 24565`
(32767-8-2-8192=24565)

But I still get PHP Warning. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is a full code:

`php_flag display_startup_errors off`

`php_flag display_errors off`

`php_flag html_errors off`

`php_flag log_errors on`

`php_value error_log /path/log/error_log.log`

`php_value error_reporting 24565`

Comment: What happens if you add `var_dump(ini_get('error_reporting'));` above the line where the warning is displayed? Does it equal 24565?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is impossible to check the php code since it is not provided, here are a few things you can do.

### Test the following script:

#### test.php

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED);

var_dump(ini_get('error_reporting'));
trigger_error("Test", E_WARNING);
```

Run `php test.php`.
The output should be: `string(5) "24565"`, without any warning displayed.

### Test if .htaccess values are accepted

Include this in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value error_reporting 24565
```

Now test if the value is accepted by PHP:

#### test.php

```
var_dump(ini_get('error_reporting'));
trigger_error("Test", E_WARNING);
```

Run with `php test.php`.
It should output `string(5) "24565"`, no warning displayed.

### Check to see if error_reporting gets overwritten somewhere in your PHP code:

Look for the following functions:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', /* some value */);
error_reporting(/* some value */);
```

Comment: First test return string(5) "24565"
Second test return string(5) "24567"

Comment: the second returns 24567? Instead of 24565?

Comment: > the second returns 24567? Instead of 24565? 
yes

Thank you very much! I think some server configuration could overwrite it. I will search for that.

Comment: that could mean .htaccess it not enabled, or at least php_value is not accepted.